# Showing a chart for features displayed using dynamic feature clustering

Tags: arcgis-pro, clustering, dynamic

I'm working on a project in ArcGIS Pro 2.9 where I'd like to be able to display categorical attribute breakdowns for each cluster that dynamically populates. Right now, the mode of that attribute is showing but I'd like my clusters to display the percentage of each category rather than the one with the highest frequency.

I see that the type of variable display I'd like is an option for individual features:

[image: Primary Symbology Options for Features]

However, it does not seem to be an option to display clusters in the same way. Here are the symbology options for clusters:

[image: Primary Symbology Options for Clusters]

I don't know if there's something particular about the way clusters are produced that makes this difficult to do. Does anyone know of some workaround so that I can display a pie chart for each cluster showing the sum of a numeric attribute grouped into pie slices based on a categorical attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the symbology options for dynamically clustered features are limited.

In order to show the data as you would like, it might require transforming the data inside ArcGIS Pro. Transpose may be helpful with this process but can only do so much. To flatten the data, it may make sense to work on it in Excel before bringing it into Arc.

Or you could settle for a different way to symbolize your data.